# Connecting points to regression line in plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

Consider the following data from the [ISLR book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/):

```
Income <- structure(list(X = 1:30, Education = c(10, 10.4013377926421, 
10.8428093645485, 11.2441471571906, 11.6454849498328, 12.0869565217391, 
12.4882943143813, 12.8896321070234, 13.2909698996656, 13.7324414715719, 
14.133779264214, 14.5351170568562, 14.9765886287625, 15.3779264214047, 
15.7792642140468, 16.2207357859532, 16.6220735785953, 17.0234113712375, 
17.4648829431438, 17.866220735786, 18.2675585284281, 18.7090301003344, 
19.1103678929766, 19.5117056856187, 19.9130434782609, 20.3545150501672, 
20.7558528428094, 21.1571906354515, 21.5986622073579, 22), Income = c(26.6588387834389, 
27.3064353457772, 22.1324101716143, 21.1698405046065, 15.1926335164307, 
26.3989510407284, 17.435306578572, 25.5078852305278, 36.884594694235, 
39.666108747637, 34.3962805641312, 41.4979935356871, 44.9815748660704, 
47.039595257834, 48.2525782901863, 57.0342513373801, 51.4909192102538, 
61.3366205527288, 57.581988179306, 68.5537140185881, 64.310925303692, 
68.9590086393083, 74.6146392793647, 71.8671953042483, 76.098135379724, 
75.77521802986, 72.4860553152424, 77.3550205741877, 72.1187904524136, 
80.2605705009016)), .Names = c("X", "Education", "Income"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

I want to reproduce their plot, which connects the points to the regression line to represent the error term, that is:

[image]

It is easy to plot the points and the regression line with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(Income, aes(Education, Income)) + geom_point(color="red")+geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

But I could not think of an easy way to connect the points to the regression line like they did.

Is there an easy way do it (with either `base`, `ggplot2` or `lattice`)?

Comment: Look at `geom_segment` and pass use `aes(x = xvals, xend = xvals, y = yvals, yend = fittedvals)` where `xvals` and `yvals` are the observed x and y coordinates for the data in the data frame you pass to `ggplot()`, and `fittedvals` is the vector of fitted values also inthe data frame obtained from `fitted(mod)` (where `mod` is your linear model object from `lm()`). So this means you need to fit the model explicitly. Similar code can be done using base graphics, in which case see `?segments`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Prelim code

```
require("ggplot2")

mod <- loess(Income ~ Education, data = Income)
Income <- transform(Income, Fitted = fitted(mod))
```

#### ggplot version

```
ggplot(Income, aes(Education, Income)) + 
  geom_point(color="red") + 
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method = "loess") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Education, y = Income,
                   xend = Education, yend = Fitted))
```

#### base graphics version

```
plot(Income ~ Education, data = Income, type = "p", col = "red",
     cex = 1.25)
points(Fitted ~ Education, data = Income)
lines(Fitted ~ Education, data = Income, col = "blue")
with(Income, segments(Education, Income, Education, Fitted))
```

Adjust accordingly to suit your aesthetic needs.

[image]